# How to convert a large XML file into a JSON file?

Tags: xml, json, converters

I've started programming 3 days ago for iOS as a hobby.
I've created a CoreData file and I need to convert a large XML file into a Json in order to move on to the next step.

I've tried a lot of online converters but my file is to large to work.

Any software you guys can recommend?
Much appreciated.

Thanks,

F

Comment: (a) how large is large? (b) some XML can't be readily converted to JSON at all - especially XML using mixed content. Converters aren't interchangeable, they all tackle this problem in different ways.

Comment: It's about 188mb!
I understand this, any ways I can at least try to import it?
Cheers,

Comment: That's big for an online service, but should be within the reach of tools you can install on your own machine. I can't advise on a specific tool, however.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this very nice node.js library to accomplish the same thing:

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

When this fails (due to memory issues or something), you may want to fall back to somehting like

https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js

and parse the XML while streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a paid app for Mac, which can convert huge XML files to JSON (it would be no issue to convert 188MB at all).

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xmltojson-converter-for-big/id1136463292?mt=12